# Find four consecutive numbers in an Arithmetic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find four consecutive numbers in an Arithmetic Progression such that when 2,6,7 and 2 are subtracted from these numbers respectively, the numbers are in geometric progression.

This is my working:

Let the 4 numbers be $T_1, T_2, T_3$ and $T_4$.

$\begin{align} T_1=a \tag {1}\end {align}$

$\begin{align} T_2= a+d \tag {2}\end {align}$

$\begin{align} T_3= a+2d \tag {3} \end {align}$

$\begin {align} T_4= a+3d \tag {4} \end {align}$

The terms in the geometric progression is: $T_1 -2, T_2-6, T_3 -7 $and $T_4 - 2$.

So, they have a common ratio.

$\frac{T_2-6}{T_1-2} = \frac{T_3-7}{T_2-6}$

$(T_2-6)^2=(T_3-7)(T_1-2)$

Substituting $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ into the equation:

$\begin{align}(a+d-6)^2 &= (a+2d-7)(a-2)\\(a+d-6)(a+d-6) &=a^2-2a+2ad-4d-7a+14\\a^2+ad-6a+ad+d^2-6d-6a-6d+36 &= a^2-2a+2ad-4d-7a+14\\ 2ad-3a+d^2-8d+22&=0\tag {5}\end{align}$

And I also took $(T_3 -7)^2=(T_4-2)(T_2-6)$

$\begin{align} (a+2d-7)(a+2d-7)&=(a+3d-2)(a+d-6)\\a^2+2ad-7a+2ad+4d^2-14d-7a-14d+4a&=a^2+ad-6a+3ad+3d^2-18d-2a-2d+12\\-2a+d^2-10d-12&=0\\2a=d^2-10d-12\tag{6}\end{align}$

Substituting $(6)$ into $(5)$

$(d^2-10d-12)d-3(\frac{d^2-10d-12}{2})+d^2-8d+22=0$

$2d(d^2-10d-12)-3(d^2-10d-12)+2d^2-16d+44=0$

$2d^3-20d^2-24d-3d^2+30d+36+2d^2-16d+44=0$

$2d^3-21d^2-10d+80=0$

But then, d=10.62 or 1.88 which  should be wrong because d is usually an integer.

Is there a simpler way to solve this (I’m still a student) or did any of my computations go wrong?

Comment: Hint:  Multiplication is nearly *always* easier to do that addition.  So start with the geometric series terms $a, ra, r^2a, r^3a$ and figure the arithmetic sequence is $a+2, ra+6, r^2a+7, r^3a+2$ and $d= (ra+6-a-2)=(r^2a+7-ra-6)=(r^3a+2-r^2a-7)$.  You'll find that is *much* easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the geometric sequence.

Let the four terms of the geometric series be

$a, ra, r^2a,r^3a$ and so the four terms of the arithmetic series are

$a+2, ra+6, r^2a+7, r^3a+2$

1) So $d = (ra+6)-(a+2) = (r-1)a +4$.

2) And $d = (r^2a+7)-(ra+6) = (r-1)ra + 1$

3) And $d = (r^3a + 2)- (r^2a +7) = (r-1)r^2a -5$.

Combining 1) and 2)so $(r-1)a + 4 = (r-1)ra + 1$ so

$(r-1)ra - (r-1)a = 4-1$ so

A)$(r-1)^2a = 3$

Combining 2) and 3) $(r-1)ra + 1 =(r-1)r^2a -5$

$(r-1)r^2a - (r-1)ra = 6$

B)$(r-1)^2ra = 6$.

Dividing B by A we get $r= 2$.

And $(r-1)^2 a=a=3$

so the arithmetic sequence is $5,12, 19,26$ and the geometric sequence is $3,6,12,24$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As there are four elements in Arithmetic Progression,

let they be $$a-3d,a-d,a+d,a+3d$$

$$\dfrac{a-d-6}{a-3d-2}=\dfrac{a+d-7}{a-d-6}=\dfrac{a+3d+2}{a+d-7}$$

Solve $$\dfrac{a-d-6}{a-3d-2}=\dfrac{a+d-7}{a-d-6}$$

$$\dfrac{a+d-7}{a-d-6}=\dfrac{a+3d+2}{a+d-7}$$

There will be nice cancellations

Comment: How do you get the first term to be a-3d and so on?

Comment: @gc3941d, As the number of terms are even we can use the following pattern $$a\pm d,a\pm3d,\cdots$$ to ease off the calculation. Had the number of terms been odd, the pattern could be $$a, a\pm d, \cdots$$